# Swap never used. Should I delete it?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, disk, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Importance of Swap Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9092/importance-of-swap-partition)

I have an extended partition with 32GB assigned, 4.3GB goes to swap and the rest is formated as ext4.

From time to time I open the system monitor and every time I see that swap is never used.

Should I delete swap in this case?