# Swap space too little

Tags: swap

My machine is running Ubuntu 12.10 with Gnome 3.6; I have 2GB of RAM and I have allocated **1** GB of swap space during installation. And I am not running out of it anytime (as I'm aware/think so), acording to my *swap memory applet* the average is around 10-15%. But I am still a way less that recommended, as [here explained](https://askubuntu.com/a/49138/156684). **Could I be facing any potential problem about it?**

- If so, what? And should I increase *my* Swap space anyway?

---

P.S.
I have read about the [Importance of Swap Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9092/importance-of-swap-partition).
Also about [How to increase SWAP space in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space-in-ubuntu) and more...
But I couldn't find the answer I am looking for.

Comment: I think that you can face problem when hibernating your computer, as the memory could be saved to the swap. The only time when my PC really use Swap, is when I have many virtual machine running in Virtual Box. (I have 8Gb of RAM and 10Gb of Swap). It all depends of what you do with your PC, and the need of your applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I be facing any potential problem about it?

No.

> If so, what?

Unless you like to keep hundreds of tabs with lots of images and try to open several GiB files with GIMP you are OK.

> And should I increase my Swap space anyway?

In this case apply the rule *if it's not broken, why fix it?*. You only should increase your swap partition when you are getting OOM's, otherwise an excessive big swap will be most of the time unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see is that if you were  to edit a huge photograph or play a memory hungry game, there may be a lot of disk  activity.

If that would be a problem for you, you can easily adjust the swap file in gparted available from the Software Centre.

Comment: As I understand, swap SPACE is just another partition on my HDD. So I'll need unallocated space in order to extend my **swap** space? Can I just lower the size of the partition beside swap "space"?

Comment: It depends how the other partitions are formatted ext4 not a problem other formats may take longer.