# Dual Booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I want to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo G510. The problem is that I can't install alongside Windows 10 for some reason. I'm reinstalling Windows 10 for other reasons, so I wondering if there is a way I can fix the problem. Also, What us swap partition and is it necessary to have? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure Windows fast start up or always on hibernation is off. If Windows is installed in UEFI mode, be sure to boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 8 screens
http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system
 If you have 4GB of RAM or more you may only need a smaller swap. Hibernation if dual booting not recommended. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: 15.04 is no longer supported on Ask Ubuntu,

Answer (score 1):

As this question contains many sub-questions and seems to be answered already to other related questions ...so, this might help you :

Installing Windows:
[**How to Install Windows After I've Installed Ubuntu?:**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Installing Ubuntu with manual partitioning : [**Installing Ubuntu Alongside Windows:**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

About SWAP:

[**Importance of Swap Partition:**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9092/importance-of-swap-partition)

[**What is a “Swap Area?:**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508870/what-is-a-swap-area)

Note : If you find these answers useful, please don't forget to up-vote the **original** answers.

Comment: Severus, in case of future deletion of posted links, please make small summaries of the important points of each into your question. I will start

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice Thanks, I appreciate your edit, But As the 'links to the answers' I have used in my Answer are of very high quality, I strongly doubt that it would be deleted. And I think  providing an extremely long answer is not always helpful. I mean no offence by this.